# FirefoxDriver gives NullPointerException

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, maven-2, selenium, continuous-integration

i am trying to run **selenium tests** as part of **maven build**, so i followed the configuration in this document:

http://www.gitshah.com/2010/10/how-to-run-selenium-tests-as-part-of.html

but when trying to run my test class:

```
public class LoginTest {

    private WebDriver driver;
    private String baseUrl;
    private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        baseUrl = "http://localhost:8080/";
    }

    @Test
    public void testLoginClass() throws Exception {
        driver.get(baseUrl + "/MyApp/login");
        driver.findElement(By.id("j_username")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("j_username")).sendKeys("1");
        driver.findElement(By.id("j_password")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("j_password")).sendKeys("123456");
        driver.findElement(By.id("loginBtn")).click();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        driver.quit();
        String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
        if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
            fail(verificationErrorString);
        }
    }

}
```

i am getting NullPointerException on this line:

```
driver.get(baseUrl + "/MyApp/login");
```

please advise why i am getting this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

error solved after making the test class extends **TestCase**